# Dipole moments of cis and gem alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, molecular-structure, dipole

The procedure for comparing dipole moments for *cis*- and *trans*-alkenes is quite easy, but how to compare dipole moments of

1. 1,1 dichloroethene (**1**); and
2. *cis*-dichloroethene (**2**)?

My teacher told me that **1** would have more dipole moment as both chlorines are attached to a single carbon leading to more polarisation of bond, but I was not entirely convinced as the chlorine atoms in **1** would make a $60^\circ$ angle with the horizontal (probably a little larger due to steric repulsions between the two chlorine atoms) whereas the chlorine atoms in **2** would make a only a $30^\circ$ angle with the vertical (where the dipole moment is directed) so **2** should have a greater dipole moment.

Which one is the correct answer? Also is this different for different compounds (e.g., 1,1 diflouroethene or  1,1 diflourobutene etc.)?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct, based on bond angles. Checked the data at [CCCBDB](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/DipReCalc.asp)!

Comment: Nice website...